# What is Tomcat Application Manager on NetBeans 11

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, server, credentials

I download the latest version of NetBeans (11).

When I added a Tomcat server, NetBeans asked me for credentials. 
And told me that it will create it if it not already exists.

I did this, but when I tried to connect that not seems to work at all.
And NetBeans ask me all the time to connect again...

[image]

I always used Eclipse before and there were no credentials to specify before running the server.

Is there somebody who already have this error and succeded to solve it ?

Thank you in advance,
Joss